# Mic not working suddenly on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, microphone, realtek-hd-audio

My mic is not working on Windows 10 all of a sudden. It used to work for years then suddenly it stopped working. I replaced the mic with a new, though whenever I plug in the mic the system shows a dialog detecting the mic plugged in but it fails to pickup any audio. I tried the same with Live installation of Kali Linux, there too the mic was showing but not working.
**How to detect if it's a software issue or a hardware issue and how to solve ?**
I tried rolling back windows but it did not worked.
Tried the troubleshoot option from sound settings, it did not work.
Updated to latest version of Realtek audio driver, did not worked.
Main board has 2 front jack and 3 rear jack, the mic does not work, the older one and the newer one is of 3.5mm, the new mic works on other device.

Comment: In the Windows *Privacy* CPL, under *App permissions*, click on *Microphone* to see if it's been turned off.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It's turned on still not working.

Comment: The problem was the mic was of TRRS but PC jacks come with TRS